# How to load pdf files as URL with my application in in the Open in... menu

Tags: ios, swift, nsdata, nsurl, pdfkit

I am implementing an application that I want to open pdf files Which I received from emails in my application. my application is in the list of open in... Menu, the problem is that when I choose my application to open pdf with that, it runs my application but it does not load that pdf file.

[image]

I followed this tutorial to make it happen load pdf files as URL in the app.https://pspdfkit.com/blog/2017/action-extension/ .
as the article said I should use these codes

```
let data = Data(contentsOf: fileURL)
data.write(to: targetURL, atomically: true)
```

my problem is that I do not know how to get `fileURL` and how I can Initialize it with the URL of the exact pdf file,

and also what function would be called after I choose my application to open with. 
it seems that these two functions are not called.

```
   override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) 
   {

    self.refreshData()
   }
override func viewDidLoad() 
   {
    super.viewDidLoad()
   }
```

Appreciate any help. thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure what you're asking, but if your main issue is how to set `fileURL`, then you should read: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url

example for remote url path: `let fileURL = URL(string: "https://mysite/filename.pdf")`

example for local resource url path: `Bundle.main.url(forResource: "filename", withExtension: "pdf"))`

As for your seconds question about what is called, you should read about ViewController's lifecycle: https://www.codementor.io/hemantkumar434/view-controller-lifecycle-ios-applications-7oyju9lp6

For your example, first the `viewDidLoad` is called, then `viewWillAppear`.

Comment: thank you very much, I have read the articles before but my problem still exist. I need a clear guide how to do step by step exactly. but thank you very very much. I appreciate your help very much. I updated my question with a picture of what list exactlyI am talking about.

Comment: in this way while I open pdf files with this list of open in menu, the one which I uploaded the image, first `viewDidLoad` would be called too? if so why when I debug the code it does not call it, thank you again very very much for your time and your care.

Comment: Never had an opportunity to implement one. From what I read, yes, `viewDidLoad` should be called. Maybe this can provide additional info: https://medium.com/@ales.musto/simple-text-action-extension-swift-3-c1ffaf3a197d